Can't return state from another file
I have a file main.py with this code:
MENU = range(0)

class Main():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Application.builder().token(token=config['TOKEN']).build()
        self.start_handler = Start(MENU).handler()
        self.menu_handler = Menu().handler()

    def run(self) -> None:
        conversation = ConversationHandler(
            entry_points=[self.start_handler],
            states={
                MENU: [self.menu_handler]
            },
            fallbacks=[]
        )
        self.app.add_handler(conversation)
        self.app.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)

Main().run()

Then I have another file, from where I would want to return the "MENU" state, but I can't get it work at all. The bot says to me: 'start' returned state range(0, 0) which is unknown to the ConversationHandler.
class Start():
    def __init__(self, MENU):
        self.MENU = MENU
        pass

    async def start(self, update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
        user_info = await get_user_info(update)

        keyboard = [
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton('Decline', callback_data='STOP'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton('Accept', callback_data='CHOOSE_NETWORK')
                ]
            ]
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        get_user_id = await mySQL().select('users', 'user_id', 'WHERE user_id = %s', user_info['user_id'])

        if get_user_id is None:
            await update.message.reply_text('To continue using this bot you need to accept: \n\nThis and this', reply_markup=markup)
            return CHOOSE_NETWORK
        else:
            return self.MENU

I have tried everything.

how do you instantiate the class in the second file ?

You mean how I initiate the class Start() in Main() or class Main() in Start()?

Just to add this: The Start(MENU).handler() and Menu().handler(), are ConversationHandlers()

It is due to the MENU state being defined as range(0), which is an empty range. When you return self.MENU in your Start class, it's returning this empty range, which the ConversationHandler doesn't recognize as a valid state, hence the error message.
You should define MENU as a specific integer or string that can be recognized as a state by the ConversationHandler. For example, you could define MENU as 1 or 'MENU'.
MENU = 1  # or 'MENU'

class Main():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Application.builder().token(token=config['TOKEN']).build()
        self.start_handler = Start(MENU).handler()
        self.menu_handler = Menu().handler()

    def run(self) -> None:
        conversation = ConversationHandler(
            entry_points=[self.start_handler],
            states={
                MENU: [self.menu_handler]
            },
            fallbacks=[]
        )
        self.app.add_handler(conversation)
        self.app.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)

Main().run()

And in your Start class:
class Start():
    def __init__(self, MENU):
        self.MENU = MENU
        pass

    async def start(self, update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
        user_info = await get_user_info(update)

        keyboard = [
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton('Decline', callback_data='STOP'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton('Accept', callback_data='CHOOSE_NETWORK')
                ]
            ]
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        get_user_id = await mySQL().select('users', 'user_id', 'WHERE user_id = %s', user_info['user_id'])

        if get_user_id is None:
            await update.message.reply_text('To continue using this bot you need to accept: \n\nThis and this', reply_markup=markup)
            return CHOOSE_NETWORK
        else:
            return self.MENU

This way, when self.MENU is returned, it will be a state that the ConversationHandler can recognize.

ChatGPT give me this same answer and it didn't work :'(

Can you tell me what the bot says to you after you implement the revised codes?

When I change the MENU = range(0)
to
MENU = 'MENU'
or
MENU = str('MENU')
I get the same error PTBUserWarning: 'start' returned state MENU which is unknown to the ConversationHandler.
If MENU = 0, it doesn't give me any errors nor forward the conversation to next state

Problem solved. I switched the used 'python-telegram-bot' library to aiogram.

You should complete your answer by adding the final code using the other library.
